# Wondering how I would add a random number to my api url jsreact

Tags: reactjs

As the title says I have a button that I would like to have get a different film each time I press the button.
I was thinking that I have to change the url to: 
`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieID}?api_key=${apikey}`

I've made the random id function but it's bringing up an error of unexpected token so I mightve put it in the wrong place or the something I'm really new to react so it might be a really simple mistake.

this is the whole app.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: '',
      overview: '',
      poster: '',
      vote: ''
    }
    this.getFilm=this.getFilm.bind(this);
  }

 movieID: function (props){
  var maxNumber = 284054;
  var randomNumber = Math.floor((math.random()* maxNumber )+1);

}

getFilm(){
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=${apikey}`
    axios.get(url)
    .then(data => {
      let res = data.data;
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        title: res.title,
        overview: res.overview,
        poster: res.poster_path,
        vote: res.vote_average

      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error')
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.poster);
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <h1> Lets see what you got</h1>
      <div name="title">
        {this.state.title}
      </div>
      <div name="overview">
        {this.state.overview}
      </div>
      <div name="poster_path">
        {this.state.poster}
      </div>
      <div name="vote_average">
        Vote:{this.state.vote}
      </div>
        <button onClick={this.getFilm}>Get Movie</button>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
movieID(){
  var maxNumber = 284054;
  var randomNumber = Math.floor((math.random()* maxNumber )+1);
  return randomNumber
}


getFilm = () => {
    const newMovieId = this.movieID()
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${newMovieId}?api_key=${apikey}`
    axios.get(url)
    .then(data => {
      let res = data.data;
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        title: res.title,
        overview: res.overview,
        poster: res.poster_path,
        vote: res.vote_average

      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error')
    })
  }
```

This should help you solve the problem. you have not declared the function properly and also not called it. Hope this helps

Comment: im my console im getting GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/undefined?api_key=7cab3fa448c3344f96941896421ea986 404 (Not Found)
any idea whats casuing that

Comment: Okay I managed to miss a line off that was why thank you again for your help